# Protractor Pseudo Elements

Tags: javascript, protractor, pseudo-element

I have four classes under div and when one is selected, that one class gets appended with the pseudo-element '::before'. I want to find which element has the psuedo-element, but how do I check this with protractor?

```
<div class>
     <i class>#1.... ::before</i>
     <i class>#2.... </i>
     <i class>#3.... </i>
     <i class>#4.... </i>
</div>
```

I've tried ' .getAttributes('.example_class_here') ' but ::before does not show up. I've also tried with .getComputedStyle from Javscript, but it also did not like that.

Suggestions and coding examples are appreciated!

Comment: so you want to test if the pseudo element is rendered?

Comment: Not really rendering, more like if it has been selected. Each of the <i> are clickable, ::before is the only way I can see if an item is selected.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by selected. What exactly determines whether or not a given <i> element has the pseudo-element?

Comment: By selected I mean has been clicked (like a button). One of the four <i> always has ::before. When clicked, if it is currently not selected, it removes ::before from the other <I> that used for not selected and adds ::before to the <I> for selected

Answer (score -1):

You can get the classes present in the element like:

```
element.getAttribute('class')
```

then if you want to assert if the element contains a specific class

```
expect(element.getAttribute('class')).toContain('yourClass')
```